# Debug SWAGGER on Webspehre Liberty Profile

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, websphere-liberty

I have an JAX-RS application running on IBM Websphere Liberty Profile.

Also I have included SWAGGER 1.5.3.

The application compiles fine and generates swagger files in webapp directory. But when I try to access it via URL, it says `NO API FOUND` and the spinner keep spinning.

[image]

There are no errors registered on browser console neither any errors in server console.

I do not know whats wrong with it, without any errors its hard to debug.
Where can I see the detailed errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Liberty has native support for Swagger v2 using the [apiDiscovery-1.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_api_discovery.html) feature.  If you enable that you should see your APIs in `https://host:https_port/ibm/api/docs`.

By the way, there's support for the newer OpenAPI v3 spec, via the [Microprofile OpenAPI](http://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-open-api-1.0.1/microprofile-openapi-spec.html) programming model.  You can use Liberty's [mpOpenAPI-1.0](https://openliberty.io/blog/2018/05/22/microprofile-openapi-intro.html) feature for that.

Comment: For OpenAPI you just need to include `openapi-3.0` feature, it might be a bit easier to configure than apiDiscovery.

Comment: The OP said they're using Swagger 1.5.3, which is Swagger v2.  The `openapi-3.0` feature is for OAS3